# If URL contains 'foo' find and include a matching PHP include

Tags: php

I've written some code that includes 'home.php' if the URL contains 'index.php':

```
<?php if($_GET['page'] != "index.php") {
include('_includes/home.php');  } ?>
```

This works fine for a specific page (in this instance the home page), but I want to extend this logic for any page on my site. For instance if the URL contained 'foo2.php' I'd want the the PHP to search for and include '_includes/foo2.php'.

I'm new to php so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Don`t use conditional inclusion, there must be a better way to do whatever you want to do here...

Comment: Whats wrong with conditional inclusions?

Comment: Hard to debug, variables may get overwritten...it`s a bad practice

Answer (score 1):

if the URL was:

> http://example.com/?page=foo2

```
if (empty($_GET['page'])){
  include ("_includes/index.php");
  exit;
}
$Page_Search = glob("_includes/*.php");

if (in_array($_GET['page'],$Page_Search)){
 include ("_includes/$page.'.php');
 exit;
}
```

This might be of use.

Comment: @Dan382  Then by default the browser will attempt to load foo2.php, perhaps you should look into some MVC (Model, View, Controller) frameworks, or use .htaccess to route everything through index.php (same method which MVC use)

Comment: Thanks Daryl I'll look into MVC, not something I've stumbled into before.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
if(isset($_GET['page'])) include "_includes/{$_GET['page']}.php";
```